# How to get the repository archive date in GitHub Enterprise Server 3.5.11?

Tags: git, github, github-api

I need to get the date on which a repository was archived. This information is available in UI in one of the [newer versions](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-11-23-repository-archive-date-now-shown-in-ui/#:%7E:text=Previously%2C%20you%20could%20see%20that,top%20of%20the%20repository%20view) but we are using GitHub Enterprise Server 3.5.11. Is there an API that gives this data?

The API to get repository data is only returning `"archived": true` but not the actual date.

Comment: [Repository archive date in GraphQL API](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-04-11-repository-archive-date-in-graphql-api) is encouraging, but not yet for GHE.